# How to fetch dates of Last Week of Any Month

Tags: python

I have a scenario where i want to fetch dates of last week of every month and store it to set

**For example :**

Let's assume this 2 parameter as Input :  Todays month is `JUL` and current date `date.today()`

**My code :**

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import timedelta

def fetchLastWeekdate(month_name,current_date):
    today = date.today()

    for i in range(0,7):
        print (today - timedelta(days=i))
```

**Printing Output :**

```
2021-07-25
2021-07-24
2021-07-23
2021-07-22
2021-07-21
2021-07-20
2021-07-19
```

**Expected Output :**

But I need expected Output as following -> `25,26,27,28,29,30,31` as set

```
my_last_week_set  = {25,26,27,28,29,30,31}
```

Comment: Why are you passing `current_date` if you aren't going to use it?  Actually, why do you have *any* parameters since you don't use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also tried but the approach is little bit different , but it work like charm

**My code :**

**Approach 1**

```
import time
import calendar

my_list = time.strftime("%Y,%m")
tdetails=my_list.split(',')

#Get last date of month 
lastdateofmonth=calendar._monthlen(int(tdetails[0]), int(tdetails[1]))

lastweekdates = [ lastdateofmonth-int(x) for x in range(0,7) ]
print(lastweekdates)
```

**Output :**

[image: Output]

**Approach 2**

Incase want to try for any other month , take values from user like year , month

```
yr=int(input('Input your year : '))
mth=int(input('Input your month : '))
lastdateofmonth=calendar._monthlen(yr, mth)
lastweekdates = [ lastdateofmonth-int(x) for x in range(0,7) ]
print(lastweekdates)
```

**Output :**

[image: Output]

**Approach 3 : using map**

```
import time
import calendar

year , month = map(int,time.strftime("%Y %m").split())
lastdateofmonth=calendar._monthlen(year, month)
lastweekdates = [ lastdateofmonth-int(x) for x in range(0,7) ]
print(lastweekdates)
```

**Output :**

[image: Output]

If want to sort the last week dates of output just use : `sorted()`

```
print(sorted(lastweekdates))
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas has some nice date features. Here I generate all last Sundays of the month in 2021 (if week start Monday as in Europe use weekday=0):

```
import pandas as pd

last_sunday_of_month = list(
    pd.date_range(start="1/1/2021", end="1/1/2022", freq="M")
    - pd.offsets.Week(weekday=6)
)
```

Then print all of the dates of the end of each month - here as lists. Conver to set will mess up the order:

```
for i in last_sunday_of_month:
    print(pd.date_range(i, i + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(1)).strftime("%d-%m").tolist())
```

Output:

```
['24-01', '25-01', '26-01', '27-01', '28-01', '29-01', '30-01', '31-01']
['21-02', '22-02', '23-02', '24-02', '25-02', '26-02', '27-02', '28-02']
['28-03', '29-03', '30-03', '31-03']
['25-04', '26-04', '27-04', '28-04', '29-04', '30-04']
['30-05', '31-05']
['27-06', '28-06', '29-06', '30-06']
['25-07', '26-07', '27-07', '28-07', '29-07', '30-07', '31-07']
['29-08', '30-08', '31-08']
['26-09', '27-09', '28-09', '29-09', '30-09']
['24-10', '25-10', '26-10', '27-10', '28-10', '29-10', '30-10', '31-10']
['28-11', '29-11', '30-11']
['26-12', '27-12', '28-12', '29-12', '30-12', '31-12']
```

The solution include the last whole week. Eg. last day of month is a sunday - then the whole last week is included.

Answer (score 0):

```
import calendar as c
num_days = (c.monthrange(2021, 7)[1]) - 6
my_last_week_lst = [num_days + i for i in range(7)]
my_last_week_set = set(my_last_week_lst)
print(my_last_week_set)
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned Pandas `date_range` would be useful here.

The following function will take the month name or number, and an optional year, and return the last 7 days of the specified month.

If you don't specify the year it defaults to the current year.

```py
import pandas as pd

def fetchLastWeekdate(month_name, year=pd.to_datetime('today').year):
    first_day = f'{year}-{month_name}-1'
    last_day = pd.date_range(start=first_day, periods=1, freq='M').format()[0]
    days = [date.day for date in pd.date_range(start=first_day, end=last_day,freq='D').to_list()[-7:]]
    return days
```

```
>>> fetchLastWeekdate('FEB')
[22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]
>>> fetchLastWeekdate('FEB', 2020)
[23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
>>> fetchLastWeekdate('DEC', 1983)
[25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]
```